# ElasticSearch Regex Query No data

Tags: elasticsearch

Why does my regex query not find this document.

[image]

Document

[image]

I do not want to find message looking like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove the dollar sign from your regexp expression.

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": "I,.* "
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATEs** (from my comments)

- **Why the dollar sign doesn't work**? IMHO, the [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators) is a bit misleading. The first paragraph (the one that mentions `^` and `$` anchors) talks about "*most regular expression engines*", but not of Elasticsearch. In fact, the following paragraph says that "*Lucene’s patterns are always anchored*", and as Lucene powers Elasticsearch, you won't need to define explicitly `^` and `$` in your regexp.
- **Performance**. This kind of query is a very expensive one, and can quickly kill performance. I'd suggest rethinking either the structure and/or the mapping of your documents.

Comment: I need to find only the messages ending in space. If I do as you suggest, I would get other messages.

Comment: Just add one whitespace after the star symbol (updated my answer). But, careful, a query like that is going to be very expensive in terms of performance. I'd suggest you rethink the structure of your documents and/or their mapping.

Comment: Yep realize the costs. Why does trailing $ not work?

Comment: I'm afraid the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_standard_operators) is a bit misleading. In my interpretation, the first paragraph (the one that mentions ^ and $ anchors) talks about "most regular expression engines", but not Elasticsearch. In fact, the following paragraph says that "Lucene’s patterns are always anchored", and as Lucene powers Elasticsearch, you won't need to define explicitly ^ and $ in your regexp

Comment: Hi, is the question answered? Was it helpful?